# Tracking log file for error in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my codeigniter application I am repeatedly getting this error message in log files.

`ERROR - 2016-06-10 00:15:19 --> 404 Page Not Found: /index`

How to know what is causing this error, as me and my team have ran through whole website multiple times and didnt found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your application you're hitting /index ( eg. www.example.com/index) .. but you don't have a controller named Index.php defined. Thus resulting in 404 Page Not Found.

Comment: I have checked all my controllers. All of them have index function and only 1 main index.php file. Is there a way to log back traced 404 errors within CI.

Comment: hitting example.com/index won't look for index method in any of your controllers, instead look for controller named Index. Do you have a controller named Index defined?

Comment: I have added a debug_backtrace to 404 function, lets wait for results.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a route defined as `index`, or you don't have a controller defined as `Index`. A 404 Error is exactly that. The page wasn't found.

From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:

> 10.4.5 404 Not Found
>
> The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No
>   indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or
>   permanent.
>
> If the server does not wish to make this information available to the
>   client, the status code 403 (Forbidden) can be used instead. The 410
>   (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some
>   internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently
>   unavailable and has no forwarding address.